# Python package structure - submodules

Tags: python, package

My question is more theory than specific, but if you are developing a Python package where two subpckages (same level) need each other to function, should you keep them still as separate child packages because their organization makes sense to separate based off their purposes or make them a single subpackage because they are necessarily intertwined?

I am not sure if there is a straightforward answer here and would like some input from the more seasoned Python community- what is considered "more Pythonic"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subpackages should be in separate child packages that make sense in terms of structure and functionality.

Just as classes, it makes them easier to understand and maintain and upgrade in the future. It also makes them potentially reusable for other applications.

Comment: So for them to import each other is secondary- that shouldn't decide for me the structure of the package as a whole?

Comment: Packages and subpackages can surely import and use one or several other subpackages. It should not impact the logical structure of your project.

Comment: Awesome thanks @BUZZE - I think I am getting hung up on making sure everything remains "pythonic"

Comment: Sure @MattMurray feel free to up this post and mark as answered if it was helpful. Thanks! Good luck with your project